# get data read from file.data

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, postgresql-9.4

I'm not sure what I need to do to compare both elements, I know that I need to read the data file an I've a class to do that.

```
/**
 * Helper methods to manage file content.
 */
public class FileUtilities {

    /**
     * Reads a comma separated file from the classpath.
     */
    public List<List<String>> readFileFromClasspath(String file)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        return readFileFromBufferedReader(bufferedReader);
    }

    /**
     * Reads a comma separated file from the filesystem.
     */
    public List<List<String>> readFileFromFilesystem(String file)
            throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        return readFileFromBufferedReader(bufferedReader);
    }

    /**
     * Reads a comma separacted file from a Reader.
     * <ul>
     * <li>Lines started with '#' are ignored.</li>
     * <li>Spaces before and after the comma are ignored.</li>
     * <li>Fields can be surrounded by quotes.
     */
    private List<List<String>> readFileFromBufferedReader(
            BufferedReader bufferedReader) throws FileNotFoundException,
            IOException {
        List<List<String>> fileRows = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        while (line != null && line.length() > 0) {
            if (line.charAt(0) != '#') {
                List<String> rowValues = new ArrayList<String>();
                String[] tokens = line
                        .split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))");
                for (String token : tokens) {
                    String processedToken = stripQutoes(token);
                    rowValues.add(processedToken);
                }
                fileRows.add(rowValues);
            }
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        return fileRows;
    }

    private String stripQutoes(String token) {
        String tokenWithoutSpaces = token.trim();
        if (tokenWithoutSpaces.length() > 0) {
            if (tokenWithoutSpaces.charAt(0) == '"'
                    && tokenWithoutSpaces
                            .charAt(tokenWithoutSpaces.length() - 1) == '"') {
                return tokenWithoutSpaces.substring(1,
                        tokenWithoutSpaces.length() - 1);
            }
        }
        return tokenWithoutSpaces;
    }
}
```

Also when I read the data file, I've no error so I suppose that I read correctly, moreover, I've achieved to connect correctly java with database using *Eclipse Luna 4.4.0* and *PostgreSQL 9.4*.

This is a part of a main class that I have:

```
public class Exercise1UpdateOrInsertDataFromFile {
    private FileUtilities fileUtilities;

    public Exercise1UpdateOrInsertDataFromFile() {
        super();
        fileUtilities = new FileUtilities();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Exercise1UpdateOrInsertDataFromFile app = new Exercise1UpdateOrInsertDataFromFile();
        app.run();
    }

    private void run() {

        List<List<String>> fileContents = null;
        try {
            fileContents = fileUtilities.readFileFromClasspath("exercise1.data");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: File not found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("ERROR: I/O error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (fileContents == null) {
            return;
        }
        //at this point we asume that we read from file exercise1.data

        DBAccessor dbaccessor = new DBAccessor();
        dbaccessor.init();
        Connection conn = dbaccessor.getConnection();
```

---

EDIT

I've replaced my answer for another more exact and simplest.

I need an example about how to get for example the first line read from data file, If I know how to get data maybe I'll do the next part. I guess I should use fileUtilities somehow but don't know what.

This is the content of file.data:

```
# Doc_Nmber, Pat_Number, Visit_Date, Price
26902,6574405,30/03/2011,315
26507,6392432,14/03/2010,322
35356,6574405,15/02/2011,475
35252,9062865,07/07/2011,140
```

The table that I need to update have the same kind of content.

Comment: It's not really clear what your exercise is supposed to do, and what data is in those files and those tables. Perhaps you should give the exact wording of your exercise.

Comment: I add the file content. I can't post all the exercise because is large volume of code. This is a workbook problem and all classes ara predefinied, I only did the correct conection to database and now I need how to manage the data read.

Comment: Basically, there are usually some fields in each row which are considered its "key". And each combination of them is unique. You retrieve the data from the database using those keys. That's the only hint I can give you without understanding what the exercise actually is supposed to do.

Comment: Yes, I know that I need to use primary key to compare table and data, but I don't know how to get this data, what's the correct instruction for example to get the first row read in data file?

Comment: It's the other way around - you read the data from the file serially. You read it from the database based on the primary key.

Comment: But my data file is inside of src folder in my project, and I read this data from here, also, I read the data from database. My problem is how to get the data read from data file. Sorry about my english, maybe I can't explain myself as well as that I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've the solution, it's quite simply use:

```
fileContent.get(index)
```

i used that in a `System.out.println` and it works, now I need to check if I can use that to compare with the database table (it's my question before EDIT), if someone knows a better way or knows that I'm wrong somehow, say me some, if not, tomorrow I'll accept my answer as correct.

Thanks!